# async code or cron job?

Tags: plugin-development

could you advise me on what is the best method to deal with this case.

I work in a task in which when uploading a file with xlsx extension I must process the information of this file and include the data in metadata of a post. There may be several hundred records in the .xlsx file. The logic is implemented. But the process may take several minutes. My questions is: What is the correct way to do so that this process is executed in the background and when it conclude notify the user with some message in the view. I thank you for your comments.